# Can PHP page compile and run Java Code

Tags: java, php, compiler-construction

Would like to create a site for my school to let student submit the java code and compile run the code and submit to answer.

Comment: [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) ?

Comment: You'll probably want a sandbox...

Comment: Answer: yes. Question: what have you tried?

Comment: Saw a API called PHP-Java Bridge still looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

php [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) is what you are looking for..probably

Comment: It is requried that the hosting server support Java?

Comment: @user236501 lol please do some research. It sounds just too dumb. Sorry to be so rude. I hope you have a VPS/dedicated server.